# Make SlideDown wait for SlideUp to finish before it triggers

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of information that are display under every product but If I hover the mouse over them really fast, everyone is sliding up and down and it doesn't look good, it's a big mess.

What I would like to do is that the jQuery wait until a slideDown animation finish before to trigger the slideUp one.

My jQuery code is:

```
    $('.title').on('mouseenter', event => {
    $(event.currentTarget).siblings().slideDown();
});
$('.box').on('mouseleave', event => {
    $(event.currentTarget).children('.info').slideUp();
});
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Take a look at the hover intent plugin, it was created to help solve issues like this by not queuing up a bunch of calls to an event when hover in/out happen really quickly: https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @clav

With the hoverIntent  plugin and doing:

```
$('.box').hoverIntent(mouseInTriger, mouseOutTriger);

function mouseInTriger() {
    $(this).children('.info').slideDown();
}
function mouseOutTriger() {
    $(this).children('.info').slideUp();
}
```

Everything is working fine now.